# multiple cascade paths sql server 2017 create self referencial foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-delete, self-reference

I have this create table script

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
  Id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
  ParentId int null,
  [Order] int default 0,
  Published bit not null default 0,
  Deleted bit not null default 0,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Categories_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Categories_ParentId FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES  Categories(Id) on delete     cascade,
  Title nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
  CreatedAt DateTime not null default GETDATE(),
  UpdatedAt DateTime not null default GETDATE()
 );
```

and i get an error

```
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Categories_ParentId' on table 'Categories' may cause   cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify    other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

how to add on delete cascade to the foreign key constraint ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server just does not allow referential actions on self-referencing foreign keys - as opposed to some other databases.

One possible workaround would be to use an `instead of delete` trigger, that follows the relationships and delete all children rows:

```
create trigger trg_categories
on categories 
instead of delete
as
    with cte as (
        select id from deleted
        union all
        select cte.id 
        from cte
        inner join categories cat on cat.parentid = cte.id
    )
    delete cat
    from categories cat
    where exists (select 1 from cte where cte.id = cat.id)
;
```